# td tag with expander class in Zurb Ink is necessary?

Tags: zurb-ink

Is it necessary to add a **td** tag with class **expander** inside every table containing one or more **td** tags? I had a issue with sub-grid which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412609/subgrid-nested-under-column-with-offset-is-not-working). I solved it by adding

```
<td class="expander"></td>
```

after the last the **td** tag using **sub-columns** and it did solve the problem. Also, the Ink documentation doesn't explicitly specify whether to to add the expander.

Answer (score 0):

td.expander must added inside every table:

http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs.html#if-fullWidth